# Almost sure bound for maximal of Gaussian R.V.

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, almost-everywhere

The following two questions come from some steps of my thought about solving an exercise. Thanks for help.

---

Let $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n, ...$ be i.i.d $N(0,1)$ random variables.

Define $M_n:=\max_{1\leq i \leq n} X_i$, for all $n\geq 1$.

Do we have that, almost surely, $M_n$ is bounded for all $n$?

One more question, do we have that, almost surely, $M_n\neq 0$ for all n?

Thanks.

Comment: $X_1$ with a normal distribution is not bounded, so why should $\max\limits_{1\leq i \leq n} X_i$ be?

Comment: The second questions is easy: Yes, $M_n \ne 0$ almost surely, because it's a continuous random variable. It doesn't have to be the maximum of anything, nor normally distributed, this comes from it simply being a continuous random variable. Perhaps a more interesting question would be, if $M_n > 0$ almost surely?

Comment: @Henry Yes, thanks.

Comment: @DanielP Hi Daniel, I have a question. Some people define *continuous random variable* as a R.V. with continuous CDF. And I know the classic trick to prove $P(M_n =0)=0$ with the continuity of CDF. But on Wikipedia, it defines a continuous random variable as a R.V. with an uncountably infinite range, cf. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Definition). If we use this latter definition, do we still have that $P(X=0)=0$ for any general continuous R.V. $X$?

Comment: I would say that "uncountably infinite range" or support was not the definition of a continuous random variable (a mixture of discrete and continuous random variables would have the same property).